# QAF -how to print /access common step Store () value into variable

Tags: qaf

I am new to QAF. I m using common steps to store value into one variable and need to assert one locator has that value.

```
store(Object val, String var);
store(2000, “currnetBalance”);
```

I need to do below activity.

1. System.out.println(${varname})
2. How to pass asserttext(“//@[availableText]”, ${varname})

I tried to pass single quotes, double quotes, concatenate string not able to print result.

Comment: are you doing UI or webservices automation?

Answer (score 1):

you can access stored variable from configuration manager. Use ConfigurationManager.getBundle() to access them in code. For example:

```
import static com.qmetry.qaf.automation.core.ConfigurationManager.getBundle;

String val = getBundle().getString("varname");
Object val = getBundle().getObject("varname");
```